# Minimum size for UITableViewCell with AutoLayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I was following [this](http://blog.jldagon.me/blog/2013/12/07/auto-layout-and-uitableview-cells/) tutorial on how to create `UITableViewCell` with `UILabel` inside fit the height of it's content and it's working great!

I have just one little problem: I want to make a default minimum size for the `UITableViewCell` that will not let the `Cell` to get resized if the content height is smaller than this minimum size.

How could I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a minimum size by setting the constraint's `relation` to be `Greater Than or Equal`.

Chances are your height constraint is just `Equal`.